# Inductive sensor signal voltage too low, how to boost it for Arduino?

Tags: arduino, voltage, boost

I have an Inductive proximity sensor that is listed as working with 5v.

[M8 2mm sensing DC 5v Inductive Proximity Sensor NPN NO LJ8A3-2-Z/BX-5V](https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/M8-2mm-sensing-DC-three-wires-NO-LJ8A3-2-Z-BX-5V-cylinder-inductive-proximity-sensor/1162433_32568347298.html)

It was the model recommended.

When using 5 V, I get 0 V, and only 2 V when triggered. Using 12 V, I get 0 V  and 2.85 V triggered.

I'm using this with an Arduino Mega, and the 2.85 V is not being read as a HIGH.

What can I do to boost the voltage to trigger the Arduino?

What is the voltage threshold to go High on the digital input?

I have set PULL UP resistor in the arduino Mega (5 V).

I was thinking using a transistor or resistor?

Comment: a transistor and a resistor are pretty very extremely much different things. Maybe you want to illustrate what you were considering using a schematic? There's a built-in schematics editor when you edit your question, so go wild!

Comment: Please post a schematic of your setup. There's a built-in tool on the editor toolbar. Mark the colour codes of the wires.

Answer (score 1):

It says "NPN" which is probably a mistranslation of "NPN open collector".

In this case, it needs a pullup. If the micro's internal pullup is too weak, add a real pullup resistor. Maybe something like 3k3-10k.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ0dva.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The switch has an NPN output. Wire as shown.*

Tip: Don't buy stuff that isn't accompanied by datasheets.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way with no additional components needed: use an analog input on arduino

Or use an opamp

Comment: Analog input won't read an NPN switch without a pullup. Op-amp won't read NPN switch without a pull-up (and is totally unnecessary). Use a digital input for a digital signal.